# Angular: Fading out element and then setting display none

Tags: angularjs

When I click an element, I'd like another element to first fade out, and then be set to display: none.

I have the following code:

Partial:

```
<div class="main_menu_image" ng-class="{ fadeOut : MenuOpen==true }" /></div>

<div class="button" ng-click="ActivateMenu()"></div>
```

Then in my controller:

```
  $scope.MenuOpen = false;

  $scope.ActivateMenu = function(){
    $scope.MenuOpen = $scope.MenuOpen === false ? true: false;
  }
```

So when I click the button, element main_menu_image gets the class `fadeOut`. So it now fades out. But after the fading animation completes I would also like to set display to none on main_menu_image so it is completely hidden.

I don't want to resort to jQuery. Is there an Angular approved way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's very easy to do:)
Like Svein says, you can use `ng-show`, and you can use `ng-hide`.

[**Working fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3258/)

This hides things instantly though. But you can for example set a timeout, via the `$timeout` service, and set your hiding boolean in that way.

You can also use `ng-if`, this actually removes the element from the DOM if the condition is not met, rather than just setting display:none.

**Update:** [Here's a more proper fiddle showcasing what you're trying to do](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3259/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngShow. If you use the ngAnimate module, you'll have built in support for animations for most built-in Angular directives.

See here for more information:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations